# Spresense で Serial へのエラー出力を止めたい

Tags: spresense

Spresense、LTE拡張ボード　arduinoIDE、#include <LTE.h>を使用しています。
Serial.beginをしていなくても拡張ボードからのエラーがSerialから出力されます。
エラーをSerialからださないようにする方法はあるでしょうか。

Comment: 「Serial.beginをしていなくても拡張ボードからのエラーがSerialから出力されます。」とはどのような状態で、何をどうやって確かめたのでしょう？ それは他の人でも簡単に再現・調査出来ますか？ これらのヘルプ記事を参考に詳細な情報を質問記事に追記してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは

Spresenseで利用できるシリアルポート `Serial` と `Serial2` の内、 `Serial` はデバッグシリアルになるので、 `Serial.print()` で明示的に出力させたものだけではなく、各ライブラリでのエラーメッセージ表示用に使われているようです。
参照
　[1.1.2. Serial](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_serial)

もし、デバッグ用の出力をすべて消したい場合は、`Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/x.x.x/` 内のすべての `printf` をコメントアウトするなどして消してしまうしかないと思います。
もちろん、その場合必要なエラーメッセージまですべて消えてしまうので、問題が起こっても何が起こっているのかわからなくなりますが。